# Asp.net ASP:Login and forms

Tags: asp.net, forms

On my webpage, I use ASP:Login, when members login to my page, very standard.

I also have a contact-form.
When I use my contact-form, there is no problem, but when I log in as a member, at use the contact form, nothing gets submitted, but the "form page" just loads again.
If I then fill out the form again, and hit the submit-button, the information is send.

My form is build like this:

```
<asp:Panel id="NameSug" Runat="server" DefaultButton="SendSug"> 
<asp:Textbox name="NavnForslag" id="NavnForslag" runat="server" width="200" MaxLength="18" /><br/><br/>
<asp:imagebutton id="SendSug" onclick="CupName_click" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/login.gif"/>  
</asp:Panel>
```

So if I'm not logged in, and fill out the form, it sends right away. If I'm logged in, I have to hit the "send" button, fill out the form again, and hit send again.

My backend-file looks like this:

```
public partial class usercontrols_msgSystem_CupNameSugFront : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Do something
    }
    protected void CupName_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            // Do something else    
    }
}
```

My overall form-tag (I have one, that "surrounds" all the forms), looks like this:

```
 <form id="DasTeam" runat="server">
```

Also, my login-form looks like this:

```
<asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Login.aspx">
                      <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div id="login">&nbsp;

                        <asp:Panel ID="panelLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="submitLoginBtn"> 
                          <p class="tekst_alias">Alias:</p>
                          <p class="box"><asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox></p>
                            <p class="tekst"> Password:</p>

                          <p class="box"><asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox></p>
                          <p class="login"><asp:LinkButton ID="submitLoginBtn" CommandName="Login" runat="server" CssClass="loginbutton">Login</asp:LinkButton></p>
                          <p class="failure"><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal></p>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You have not given us enough information to really answer the question. You need to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I hope I have now...

Comment: That's better, but there's still some details missing. Most likely something in your `Page_Load` or `CupName_click` is causing the behavior you described. In order to have a complete example, you'll need to find the part of those functions that reproduces the behavior you've described.

Comment: Hey Mason. Thx for the Reply.
But it doesn't matter what I put in.

If i write - Response.Write("Hello world"); (in the Page_Load)
And - Response.Write("Hello world2"); (in the CupName_click)

I have to push the button twice to get the "Hello world2" statement to appear - when logged in.
If not logged in, it comes at the first push?